# Is it possible to access a private method of parent class from the child class in Java?

Tags: java

How do I call a private method in this type of parent class? What I have done is an ugly peice of code but it works though I don't think it's a real solution.

Would really appreciate some advice on how this is done. I have looked to find solution but non that have given me some clarity on the matter.

```
    public abstract class Car {

         public void passItOn(int a) {

                takesVariable(a);

         }
    private void takesVariable(int a) {

         //Process the variables
    }
```

the child:

```
     public abstract class Wheel extends Car {

     boolean a = anotherMethod();
        if(value() != a) {
          passItOn(a);
        }

     }
```

There is some issue with my accaptance rate but I am on it! All will give + marks for replies!!!

Comment: What's the point of having your method `private` if you want to use them? Better use `protected`, if you want them to be used in `derived` class.

Comment: use `protected` access modifier instead of `private`. Though your question isn't clear.

Comment: I agree with Rohit, if there is a reason not to do it -and why would there be one!-, I think your solution is ok

Comment: protected works like a charm! Thanks a million! i knew there was something i was overlooking. I humble bow to your kung-fu!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accessing a private field/method [is possible using reflection](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/12/reflection.html) *if the security manager allows it*, but strongly discouraged.

Private methods are private for a reason.  If you have access to the base class, making the method `protected` is a far better solution.

Comment: Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @HarshitGupta Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

Private methods are not inherited, and so cannot be called. If you really want to have access to this method, change its access modifier keyword (`protected` or `public`).

Comment: +1 you can only call private methods for classes in the same Java file with the same outer class. Otherwise `private` means only this class.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but private methods are also inherited, you just cannot call them in child class. This is because there is no error when you call public/protected method from parent class and they invoke private methods.

Answer (score 2):

Do this if you are fine with making it protected:

```
public class BaseClass {
    protected void whatever() {}
}
```

Or this if you want to keep it private for some reason, and it will also give your base class more control over how/when "whatever" is used:

```
public class BaseClass {
    private void whatever() {}
    protected void doWhatever() {
        if(!forSomeReasonDoNotWantThisToBeUsed()) {        
            whatever();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it `protected` if you want to reach it from subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolute no way this can be done. You cannot call a `private` method of a class from any other class(be it the extending class). It can only be accessed inside that class itself. There is a reason it is said to be `private`.

If you want it to be accessed by only the extending classes an not the outside world then use `protected` access modifier for your function.